# What is the simplest way to stub a complex interface in Java?

Tags: java, testing

My code takes an interface as input but only excercises a couple of the interface's methods (often, just getters).

When testing the code, I'd love to define an anonymous inner class that returns the test data.  But what do I do about all the other methods that the interface requires?

I could use my IDE to auto-generate a stub for the interface but that seems fairly code-heavy.

What is the easiest way to stub the two methods I care about and none of the methods I don't?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using JUnit to test, use Mocks instead of stubs.

Read Martin Fowler's seminal article "[Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)"

I recommend the [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/) framework, it works like a charm automatically Mocking your interface using reflection.  It is a bit more advanced than the code samples in Fowler's article, especially when you use the [unitils](http://www.unitils.org/summary.html) library to wrap EasyMock, so the syntax will be much simpler than that in the article.  Also, if you don't have an interface, but you want to mock a concrete class, EasyMock has a class extension.

Answer (score 1):

Check out JMock.

http://www.jmock.org/

Answer (score 0):

Write an "Adapter Class" and overwrite only the methods you care.

```
class MyAdapter extends MyClass {
  public void A() {
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the classical way is to make an abstract class with empty methods.
At least, that's how Sun did for MouseListener, creating [MouseAdapter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) to ease the use of these events.

Answer (score 0):

EasyMock or JMock are definitely the winners.  I haven't used JMock, but I know with EasyMock you can setup the Mock object according to a testing script and it will return certain values in certain situations or points during your test.  It's pretty easy to learn and get running, generally in less than an hour.